# Statistical significance of distance between difference of vectors (LDA)

Tags: statistical-significance, manova, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc, hellinger

I have an output from Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) which sums up the corpus of about 2,000 documents into 50 topics. The 2,000 documents belong to a category each (in total there are 4 categories, A-D).

So my dataset looks similar to this:

| Document No. | Category | Topic 1 | Topic 2 | Topic 3 | Topic 4 | ... | Topic 50 | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0.001 | 0.020 | 0.100 | 0.012 | ... | 0.012 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 0.121 | 0.001 | 0.002 | 0.331 | ... | 0.101 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 0.023 | 0.008 | 0.015 | 0.001 | ... | 0.004 | 1 |
| 4 | B | 0.001 | 0.012 | 0.019 | 0.002 | ... | 0.006 | 1 |
| 5 | C | 0.003 | 0.401 | 0.008 | 0.005 | ... | 0.001 | 1 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  | ... |  |  |
| 2000 | D | 0.007 | 0.001 | 0.002 | 0.007 | ... | 0.002 | 1 |

Question I:
I want to compare the different categories with each other by testing if the difference of the topic distributions are significant (note that the categories have different numbers of observations).

For example: I want to discover if the topic distribution of Category A is different from Category B and if the the topic distribution of Category C is different from Category D.

Question II:
Additionally, A and B belong to the same main category and C and D belong to another main category.
For instance, A is about tennis, B about baseball and they belong to the main category sports. C is about cars, D is about trains and the main category is transportation.
Now I want to find out if the difference between sports (A-B) is larger than between transportation (C-D) and test the difference for significance.

Current Approach to Questions I & II:
So far, I calculated the Hellinger distance (e.g. A-B) based on the mean topic distribution of each category (which ignores the distribution within a category) and tested if two categories are different by a MANOVA.
Is there a way to test if the "distance" between A and B (e.g. 0.3) is larger then the "distance" between C and D (e.g. 0.2) and if that distance is significant/not a result by chance?

Comment: Your questions concerning differences between categories mentions nothing about the 50 topics.  So maybe you mean, given Topic 1, I first want to test the mean difference between category A and B.  Then repeat for Topic 2,...,50.   Or were you planning on analyzing all the topic values together into two large samples for A vs B?

Comment: I edited my question and hope it helps to clarify.
What I am doing so far is to take the mean topic distribution over the topics 1-50 for a category (e.g. A) and compare it to the mean topic distribution over the topics 1-50 for another category (e.g. B).